# jQuery: Unable to get the values of select boxes with the same name

Tags: jquery

I have a set of select boxes with the same name. I want to get the selected values of those select boxes through jQuery and make an array.

```js
function submitboxes(){
var manufCountry = $('input[name=manufacturerCountry]').map(function(){
    return this.value;
    }).get();
    
console.log(manufCountry);
}
```

```html
<form><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="manufacturerCountry[]" id="" class="form-control customSelect"><option value="1">A</option><option value="2">B</option></select>

<select name="manufacturerCountry[]" id="" class="form-control customSelect"><option value="3">C</option><option value="4">D</option></select>
<button type="button" onclick="submitboxes();">Submit</button>
</form>
```

However, in the console, I see

> []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is always empty because your selector is not matching your HTML:

`$('input[name=manufacturerCountry]')` will search for an `input` with the name attribute equal to `manufacturerCountry`.

Your HTML however contains a `select` element with the name `manufacturerCountry[]`.
So when changing your selector to

```
$('select[name^=manufacturerCountry')
```

your code will work properly.

---

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/296382/)

Note: I've changed the event handling to remove the `onclick` attribute

---

Reference:

[jQuery attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)